# update table by using custom sql in liferay

Tags: java, mysql, liferay

I just want to update my table using custom sql in liferay 6.1, I have table with primary key auto increment not null. So whenever I am trying to update It creates a new row and instead of updating data it generate a new row. Please help me to update data using custom sql and my database is mysql.
thanks 
asif aftab

Comment: Can you share the query you used?

Comment: If your table is related to a service.xml entity, I am not sure it is a good idea to update teh table using custom sql. Liferay caches a lot of information and I don't believe the cache would be properly updated  to reflect changes in the database.